# SQL Where Clause with Delimiter

Tags: php, mysql

How do I write a SQL search statement where the input is a space separated string and each word belongs to a different column?

For example:

> **Search Input:** 2011 Audi Q7
>
> Where "2011" searches for the year,
>
> "Audi" searches for the make,
>
> and "Q7" searches for the model

I'm using AJAX to create a filter for my SQL table, here's the code I'm working with, but isn't working:

**Database**

```
|year|make|model|
----------------
|2017|Audi|Q7
----- ---- -----
 ... | ...| ...
```

**PHP**

```
public function categoryOptions() {
    $term = $this->request->input('term');
    $options = VehiclesModel::where('year', 'like', '%'.$term.'%')->where('make', 'like', '%'.$term.'%')->where('model', 'like', '%'.$term.'%')->get();
    return $options->pluck('id','year','make','model');
}
```

I think I need to use a delimiter in `'%'.$term.'%'` but not sure how thats done.

Comment: You'll need to split the term into the relevant parts before you try and build the SQL clause. If they are always going to be space delimited and always in the right order, you could do something like `$terms = explode(" ",$term);` and then search on `$terms[0]` and `$terms[1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split $term by `' '` and you will have an array with year in [0], make in [1] and model in [2]. 
Something like:

```
public function categoryOptions() {
    $term = $this->request->input('term');
    $terms = explode(' ', $term);
    $options = VehiclesModel::where('year', 'like', '%'.$terms[0].'%')->where('make', 'like', '%'.$terms[1].'%')->where('model', 'like', '%'.$terms[2].'%')->get();
    return $options->pluck('id','year','make','model');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It returned the correct result, but my response is only showing {"2011":5} which is the year and ID

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your last statement "You will have to add also the where for the model after return."